# firebase - atomic delete at multiple locations

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is there a way to perform an atomic delete in Firebase?

the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) say

> You can also delete by specifying nil as the value for another write operation such as setValue or updateChildValues...Simultaneous updates made this way are atomic: either all updates succeed or all updates fail.

but I can't get it to work. My code below returns an error

> Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at . Can only store objects of
>   type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray

Is there something I'm missing here or are the docs wrong?

```
var topNodeRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var childUpdates: [String:Any?] = [:]

childUpdates.updateValue(nil, forKey: "/owner")
childUpdates.updateValue(nil, forKey: "/pet")

topNodeRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in case anyone else runs into the same problem, I managed to fix it by using `NSNull()` instead of `nil`

```
var topNodeRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var childUpdates: [String:Any] = [:]

childUpdates["/owner"] = NSNull()
childUpdates["/pet"] = NSNull()

topNodeRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Comment: Is this still working for you? I get this error now -


`'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(updateChildValues:) Non-string keys are not allowed in object at path:`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems slightly different from what I use in this working snippet:

```
var childUpdates: [String:Any?] = [:]

childUpdates["-K9i1z2KPLzh9_OrAaQU"] = nil
childUpdates["-K9i2kfteaS7tap93Gf6"] = nil

ref?.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Comment: are you using the Firebase pod? if yes, could I know the version? the code i'm running is logically equivalent to yours, but mine ends up with an error

Comment: I didn't specify any version. But I doubt the version has anything to do with it. It seems more related to the Swift syntax for populating the dictionary. When I used your approach to populating the dictionary, I got the same error as you get. When I changed it to the snippet I shared, the error disappeared and the children were deleted. Did you try my approach? Do you still get the same error on the same line with it?

Comment: really weird, i cant add values to the dictionary using your approach. for some reason, the values do not get inserted in my dictionary. try running this in playground -> var dictio: [String:Any?] = [:]
dictio.updateValue(nil, forKey: "test")
dictio["secondTest"] = nil

Comment: I don't think this code would work with an optional type. The updateChildValues() function takes an `[AnyHashable : Any]` which is satisfied by `[String:Any]` but not `[String:Any?]`